# when do two elliptic curves over finite fields have a common point

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Given two elliptic curves over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ in the form of trivariate degree $3$ polynomial we want to find whether they have a common intersection point. This is a decision problem(I don't want to find the point of intersection.)

Its seems really easy when elliptic curves are given in their Weierstrass normal form that is :
$$y^2=x^3+A_1x+B_1 \qquad y^2=x^3+A_2x+B_2$$
Clearly this will certainly have a common point when $A_1\neq A_2$.

My question is can we test this in general ??

Also can we say something about curves of higher genus ?

Note : I want an intersection point in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ and not in ${\mathbb{F}}_p$

Comment: Two homogeneous cubics in the projective plane over an algebraically closed field have always exactly nine common points (counted with multiplicity). This is [Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem). Are you asking about the affine points only? If so, then I don't understand where *trivariate* comes from.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen YES I am talking about affine points only. I have edited the question now. Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the *resultant* of two polynomials?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am aware of the resultant of the polynomial and I know that the resultant with respect to  $x$ will have a root which is  the y co-ordinate of the common point, but I that seem to be true for common point of intersection of any curve. I am looking for an answer specific to elliptic curves.

Comment: Yes, so, if it works for any curve, it works for elliptic curves. What's the problem?